# iTerm2の Show/Hide で新しいウィンドウが立ち上がってしまう

Tags: macos, iterm

iTerm2の`Preferences -> Keys -> Show/hide iTerm2 with a system-wide hotkey`のチェックを入れて`F1`キーを設定しました。

これでシステム全体のホットキーとして`F1`で iTerm2 がアクティブになるはずだと思うのですが、既に立ち上がっているウィンドウではなく新しいウィンドウが立ち上がってしまいます。

どこか他にも設定しなければならないところがあるのでしょうか？

iTerm2 のバージョンは`Build 2.0.0.20150412`になります。

Comment: `F１`にすでに新規windowを立ち上げるショートカットキーが設定されているんではないですか？ 一応リリースノートを見る限りはそんなことはないような。https://iterm2.com/downloads.html

Comment: 一応確認してみましたが他のショートカットキーは設定されてないようです。`Profiles -> Keys` の`Load Preset` から初期化してみました代わりませんでした。そもそもここのキー設定はシステム全体ではなくiTerm内での処理のはずですし…。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Preferences -> Keys -> Show/hide iTerm2 with a system-wide hotkey`のチェックで既に立ち上がっているウィンドウがアクティブになりました。

`Preferences -> Keys -> Hotkey -> Hotkey toggles a dedicated window with profile:`のチェックがあると別のウィンドウが立ち上がるような動きをしました。チェックがついているのでしたら、外してみると改善されるかもしれません。

<環境>
MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)
Yosemite 10.10.3
iTerm2 Build 2.0.0.20150412

Comment: まさにご指摘のとおり　`Hotkey toggles a dedicated window with profile`のチェックがついていて、チェックを外したら期待通りの動作になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: `dedicated window`で「専用のウィンドウ」という意味になるんですね。単語の意味をよく理解できていませんでした。

Comment: 解決してよかったです。